# Parallax Effect With Two Divs

Tags: html, css, parallax

I Have A Small Contest With Two Divs, And I Want To Have The Second Div Scroll On Top of The First Div.

What My Contest is Without Divs: https://jsfiddle.net/r4pnrqxs/3/

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" style="text-align: center;">

   <!--images-->

</table>
<br/><br/>

<table width="100%" height="100%">

   <!--Bigger image--> 

</table>
```

When I Add The Parallax Effect It Messes The First Div, But The Effect Is What I want It To Be. https://jsfiddle.net/r4pnrqxs/2/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: I have solved it, but the problem was that the page should be like link no.1 , but was messed but with the parallax effect.